# removeFilters(filters) : Ext.util.Collection

Tags: filter, sencha-touch

Can someone please explain to me how can I use removeFilters(filters) method from Ext.util.Collection?

I've seen a similar post here: [Remove Individual Filters from Store in Sencha Touch 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898900/remove-individual-filters-from-store-in-sencha-touch-2-x) but it wasn't very helpful to me.

I have a list of contacts and I want to filter it with 2 filters for example and after that to remove only one filter. For now, I have a store that gets the data from a file but I wil make it to read data from a server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem.

```
var oldFilters=[];
var newFilter;
var store = myList.getStore();

oldFilters = store.getFilters();
newFilter = oldFilters[1]; //get the second filter
store.clearFilter();
store.setFilter([newFilter]);
```

If you want you can keep the store from sorting to speed up things.